How to get Velocity to output a LF character to a CSV file
I am usng VTL to output a CSV file from Cameo to be read into Excel. In order to output multiple lines into the same Excel cell, I need to insert a Line Feed (LF) character. I have read that I should use
#set ($lineFeed = "\n")
Line1 ${lineFeed} Line2
to get
Line1
Line2
in a single Excel cell.
Using the sample code simply outputs "\n", i.e.,
Line1 \n Line2
I also tried an interim variable:
#set ($lineFeed = "\n")
#set ($lf = ${lineFeed})
Line1 $lf $Line2
which similarly imports to Excel as:
Line1 \n Line2
I assume the "\n" is for HTML output but not for straight ASCII like CSV files. Is there a way for VTL to output the LF ASCII character?

I would do:
#set($LF = "
")

## On Windows, this will produce <CR><LF> whereas we just want <LF>
#if( $LF.length() == 2 )
  #set( $LF = $LF.substring(1, 2) )
#end

Line 1${LF}Line 2

[Edited to cover Windows OS]

If I understand your suggestion, hitting "Enter" key as the $LF string, I believe this inserts  , not just the  that Excel needs. The effect when I try your suggestion is that Excel returns back to Col A of the next line rather than inserting the  in the current cell. My challenge is to output the  without the .

Oh, I see. This is platform-specific, since what you describe will only happen on linux. Let me investigate what can be done, I'll update the answer.

Actually, I'm running Windows. I found a way to insert the ASCII (10) character  into the middle of a string variable use a goat dance of character arrays and string conversions. Even with that, once I output that string to a file, my ASCII editor shows both a  and  where only the  was inserted. This is frustrating, since I don't see anything that can be done in my code to keep Velocity from being so "helpful" that I can't do what I need to do.

So the proposed hack didn't work? Any chance that the  are inserted by another tool in your tools chain? Velocity has no reason to insert those extra  in the middle of strings.

The output file from Cameo is immediately opened in Notepad++. Turning on the display of hidden characters, it shows a CR and a LF at the end of each line, including lines where it broke up the test string at the embedded LF character. Unless Notepad++ is lying to me, I don't see any other actor that could modify the file.

Well, editors like Notepad++ are known to try to normalize line endings. They do this as a service, but sometimes it gets in the way. I would definitely not trust Notepad++ on this one.
